# Specifying Prisma's database name in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm trying to implement a microservice architecture where every microservice has its' own database. I'm using [prisma](https://prisma.io/) as a data access layer between my services and a **single** database server. Since I have a single database server I want each prisma instance to access its' own database on this server, but I didn't find an option to specify name of a database used by particular prisma instance.

So here's the question. Is there a way to specify a database name for prisma instance?

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file if it's helpful:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.14
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "${PRODUCT_PRISMA_PORT}:${PRODUCT_PRISMA_PORT}"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: ${PRODUCT_PRISMA_PORT}
        managementApiSecret: ${PRODUCT_PRISMA_SECRET}
        databases:
          product:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
  product-app:
    command: yarn start
    image: product-web
    volumes:
      - ./product-service:/usr/app
    ports:
      - "${PRODUCT_APP_PORT}:${PRODUCT_APP_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - prisma
    environment:
      PORT: ${PRODUCT_APP_PORT}
      PRISMA_ENDPOINT: ${PRODUCT_PRISMA_ENDPOINT}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the "database" key on the config:

```
 environment:
  PRISMA_CONFIG: |
    port: ${PRODUCT_PRISMA_PORT}
    managementApiSecret: ${PRODUCT_PRISMA_SECRET}
    databases:
      product:
        connector: postgres
        host: postgres
        port: 5432
        user: prisma
        password: prisma
        migrations: true
        database: ${DATABASE}
```

However, be aware that Prisma uses `pg_advisory_lock` to lock exclusive access on the database. I don't know from the top off my head if this will prevent you from running multiple Prisma instances on different PG *databases*, but I would strongly advise you to try it out with a two container setup. If the log line `Obtaining exclusive agent lock... Successful.` appears in **both** container logs, it works. If one hangs with `Obtaining exclusive agent lock...` only, it doesn't.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it works. Looks like the lock works only for a database, not the whole server. Thank you.